# predicting in tensor flow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

After training my 'parameters' (w1,w2, weights of filters in Conv net), saving them as parameters=sess.run(parameters)

I take an image img=[1,64,64,3], and pass it to mypredict(x,parameters) function to predict but it gives error. The functions are given below. Any advice of whats going wrong.

def forward_propagation(X, parameters):

```
W1 = parameters['W1']
W2 = parameters['W2']


Z1 = tf.nn.conv2d(X,W1,strides=[1,1,1,1],padding='SAME')

A1 = tf.nn.relu(Z1)

P1 = tf.nn.max_pool(A1,ksize=[1,8,8,1],strides=[1,8,8,1],padding='SAME')

Z2 = tf.nn.conv2d(P1,W2,strides=[1,1,1,1],padding='SAME')

A2 = tf.nn.relu(Z2)

P2 = tf.nn.max_pool(A2,ksize=[1,4,4,1],strides=[1,4,4,1],padding='SAME')

P2 = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(P2)

Z3 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(P2,num_outputs=6,activation_fn=None)

return Z3
```

def mypredict(X,par):

```
W1 = tf.convert_to_tensor(par["W1"])
W2 = tf.convert_to_tensor(par["W2"])
params = {"W1": W1,
          "W2": W2}

x = tf.placeholder("float", [1,64,64,3])

z3 = forward_propagation_for_predict(x, params)

p = tf.argmax(z3)

sess = tf.Session()
prediction = sess.run(p, feed_dict = {x:X})

return prediction
```

I used the same function "forward_propagation" for training the weights, but when i pass a single image, it doesn't work.

Error:

---

FailedPreconditionError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1138     try:
-> 1139       return fn(*args)
   1140     except errors.OpError as e:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(session, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1120                                  feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1121                                  status, run_metadata)
   1122

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py in **exit**(self, type, value, traceback)
     88             try:
---> 89                 next(self.gen)
     90             except StopIteration:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status()
    465           compat.as_text(pywrap_tensorflow.TF_Message(status)),
--> 466           pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
    467   finally:

FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value fully_connected_1/biases
     [[Node: fully_connected_1/biases/read = IdentityT=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@fully_connected_1/biases"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

FailedPreconditionError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 pred=mypredict(t,pp)
      2

in mypredict(X, par)
     49 
     50     sess = tf.Session()
---> 51     prediction = sess.run(p, feed_dict = {x:X})
     52 
     53     return prediction

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    787     try:
    788       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 789                          run_metadata_ptr)
    790       if run_metadata:
    791         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    995     if final_fetches or final_targets:
    996       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
--> 997                              feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
    998     else:
    999       results = []

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1130     if handle is None:
   1131       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feed_dict, fetch_list,
-> 1132                            target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1133     else:
   1134       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feed_dict,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1150         except KeyError:
   1151           pass
-> 1152       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1153 
   1154   def _extend_graph(self):

FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value fully_connected_1/biases

Answer (score 0):

You must also load the parameters from the fully connected layer.

However, I would suggest using [TensorFlow's Saver and Restore functions](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) anyhow.

For saving, here is a toy example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[2]), name='w1')
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[5]), name='w2')
saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
saver.save(sess, 'my_test_model',global_step=1000) # saving model after 1000 steps
```

The following files are stored:

```
my_test_model-1000.index
my_test_model-1000.meta
my_test_model-1000.data-00000-of-00001
checkpoint
```

So for restoring, you can first recreate the net and then load the parameters:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
 recreated_net = tf.train.import_meta_graph('my_test_model-1000.meta')
 recreated_net.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
```

Comment: Can you give me an example as how to do this, save fully connected layer weights and link it in my function. Thank you

Comment: See the link attached. If you have still questions, feel free to ask